# Documenter can't find docstring

Tags: julia, markdown, documentation, documentation-generation, docstring

I'm trying to build a documentation using `documenter.jl` and run into a weird error.
In one of the `.md` files, I have a few @docs blocks. It looks as follows:

````
##Functions
```@docs
f
```

##Some more functions
```@docs
g
```
````

(Neither f nor g comes with any args specification in the `.md` file). Now documenter can find the docstring for g, but it cannot find the one for f. The docstring looks as follows:

```
"""
    f
does some stuff.
"""
```

f and g don't both come from the same file, but both from files that are included in `my_module.jl` via `include("file")`.
The error message reads:

````
Warning: no docs found for 'f' in `@docs` block in src\reference.md
```@docs
f
```
````

I am really clueless what is happening here, does anyone have an idea?

EDIT: on github, documenter builds the documentation just fine. Only locally, it cannot find the docstrings. Is that a bug of documenter? Or could it be caused by some local settings?

Comment: EDIT: on github, documenter builds the documentation just fine. Only locally, it cannot find the docstrings. Is that a bug of documenter? Or could it be caused by some local settings?